# wordpress I have create change Password Functionality through my new Plugin in wordpress how to match the user enterd Password?

Tags: wordpress

I need password check function in wordpress for change Password functionlity.I have use wp_check_password( $opass,$pass,$user_id );  function but I got wrong results Any one Help me?

Comment: First of convert the old password in md5 format. and than pass the old password in the wp_check_password(md5($opass),$pass,$user_id ); try this way it may help u and able to change passwod of user

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you using `wp_check_password`?  According to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password), the second argument needs to be the encrypted password - are you passing it encrypted?

Take a look at `wp_authenticate_username_password` in [wp-includes/user.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/user.php#L72) to see how WordPress does it; or even call `wp_authenticate_username_password` itself.

Comment: Yes I have Passed encrypted Password by wp_hash_password( $password )Function .

Comment: I have used below function to password check functionality successfully   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
     $s=wp_check_password($opass1,$pass1,$uid); $opass1 is user entered Plain Password and $pass1 is Current user Password .